# DNS Enforcement Policies

Tags: networking, dns, wireless-router

I'm using a [D-LINK DLS 2750 U](https://www.dlink.com.au/home-solutions/DSL-2750U-n300-wireless-adsl2-modem-router), and have set DNS on the router. How do I enforce all clients to use this DNS?

Comment: With consumer-grade routers, you simply cannot.

Comment: complete enforcement is not possible without also restricting a lot of other stuff, vpn is probably easiest way around that even if u're inspecting actual packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS settings on the client will override the DNS on the router - this was by design on consumer-grade routers. If the hosts are all Windows Operating Systems, [enforce DNS via Group Policy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/294785/new-group-policies-for-dns-in-windows-server-2003).

Comment: is there an option on the router to do it because i can't access to all the devices

Comment: @M.A.Bell - A router cannot override the configuration of a client device.

Comment: ah ok I 'll search another solution

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict clients to use your DNS server by closing outgoing traffic to port `53` (TCP and UDP) with firewall. In this case clients will be unable to use external DNS servers listening on the standard DNS port.

However, they will be able to use DNS servers that use ports other than 53.